# Converting JSON to Elastic NEST query doesn't work as intended

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I'm trying to convert the following JSON to NEST, but it's not working as intended. It does match the field with the website, but it doesn't match the range, so I get some very old results.

When using Kibana to search, I send this request:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "domain": "website.com"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2020-08-03T12:37:07.821Z",
              "lte": "2020-08-18T12:37:07.821Z",
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
```

And converted to NEST:

```
SearchDescriptor<ApacheRequest> Query(SearchDescriptor<ApacheRequest> qc)
{
    var query = qc.Query(q =>
            q.Bool(b =>
                b.Filter(f =>
                    f.Bool(fb =>
                        fb.Should(sh =>
                            sh.Match(ma => ma
                                .Field(x => x.Domain)
                                .Query("website.com")
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    f => f.Range(r => r.GreaterThanOrEquals(timestamp))
                )
            )
        );

    return query;
}
```

As I said, it matches the domain, but not the range. I get results a month back, even though I've tested that my `timestamp` is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Val Gives me a `The name 'f' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found the issue.. I'm not supposed to use `.Range()` but rather `.DateRange()`. Now my query looks like this:

```
SearchDescriptor<ApacheRequest> Query(SearchDescriptor<ApacheRequest> qc)
{
    var query = qc.Query(q =>
            q.Bool(b =>
                b.Filter(f =>
                    f.Bool(fb =>
                        fb.Must(sh =>
                            sh.Match(ma => ma
                                .Field(x => x.Domain)
                                .Query("website.com")
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    f => f.DateRange(r =>
                        r.Field(fi => fi.Timestamp).GreaterThanOrEquals(from)
                    )
                )
            )
        );

    return query;
}
```